# How to create non-white UIToolbar items?

Tags: iphone

My goal is to create non-white toolbar bar items. I have tried creating with customView, this works butthen I lose the white glow when you click on the button. I tried creating with initWithImage and different alpha values (it only respect the alpha values) but that doesn't help with changing color. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a UIToolbar item with a color other than white using the `initWithImage:` initializer. That method is only for toolbar items using alpha channels for a white icon.

Your best bet is to use a custom view, then add any glow you want yourself using Core Animation. One approach is to create the image you want, create the button with that as its view, then create another "glow" image and animate its `alpha` property when the toolbar custom view receives a touch event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom toolbar, where you can use any toolbar background and colored images: http://github.com/marichka/Custom-UIToolbar

White glow is easily added by showsTouchWhenHighlighted property of UIButton